# builtins.NameError NameError: name 'flask' is not defined

Tags: python, bash, flask

I am facing this problem while running my flask.py app:

**Traceback:**

```
File "/root/sitetoggle/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/root/sitetoggle/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/root/sitetoggle/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/root/sitetoggle/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/root/sitetoggle/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/root/sitetoggle/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/root/sitetoggle/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/root/sitetoggle/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/root/sitetoggle/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/root/sitetoggle/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/root/sitetoggle/flaskr/flaskr.py", line 117, in index
    return flask.Response(inner(), mimetype='text/html')  # text/html is required for most browsers to show th$
NameError: name 'flask' is not define
```

Here is my flask and template html

**flask.py**

```
import os
import subprocess
import request

from flask import (Flask, request, session, g, redirect, url_for, abort, render_template, flash)

app = Flask(__name__) # create the application instance :)
app.config.from_object(__name__) # load config from this file , flaskr.py

@app.route('/siteOFF', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def siteoff():
   error = None
   subprocess.call(['/root/sitetoggle/flaskr/testOFF.sh'], shell=True)
   return render_template('layout.html', error=error)


@app.route('/siteON', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def siteon():
    def inner():
        proc = subprocess.Popen(
            ['dmesg'],             #call something with a lot of output so we can see it
            shell=True,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE
        )

        for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline,''):
            time.sleep(1)                           # Don't need this just shows the text streaming
            yield line.rstrip() + '<br/>\n'

    return flask.Response(inner(), mimetype='text/html')  # text/html is required for most browsers to show th$
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Flaskr</title>
<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
<div class=page>
<div>
<h4>Turn site OFF or ON </h4>
<input type="button" name="lien1" value="Turn ON site"
 onclick="self.location.href='http://10.10.1.8:5000/siteON'" style="background-color:#3cb371"
style="color:white; font-weight:bold"onclick>

<input type="button" name="lien2" value="Turn OFF site"
 onclick="self.location.href='http://10.10.1.8:5000/siteOFF'" style="background-color:#1ab171"
style="color:white; font-weight:bold"onclick>
</div>
</div>
```

I am using the flaskr app which I customized to call bash script within the flask page. Everything else is still working correctly except the two functions siteon() and siteoff() which I defined in my flask.py and trying to call them in the html page.

Comment: you need to import flask, add `import flask` or import Response from flask, in the beginning.

Comment: Is it correct to have a file named `flask.py`? Are you shadowing the module?

Comment: Yes, I am new with flask so just trying to follow tutorial for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the bad line:

```
return flask.Response(inner(), mimetype='text/html')
```

So do:

```
from flask import (Flask, request, session, g, redirect, url_for, abort, render_template, flash, Response)
```

Then:

```
return Response(inner(), mimetype='text/html')
```

Comment: Can you please let people know what is the difference? Why is this a problem? :)

Comment: Sure, the `import` statement imports classes and functions from `flask` not `flask` itself, so using `flask.*` is not valid unless you `import flask`. My solution just adds `Response` to the import since it is easy to change `flask.Response` => `Response`